# What is the most 'Pythonic' way to generate, clear, and save multiple arrays of data, one element at a time? (pandas/numpy)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm working on a [python](/questions/tagged/python) script to run some external processes and collect some data.

I have **n** input values that each need to be tested at **m** different parameter values. At each pair, I need to collect 5 different variables from an external interface, let's call them `var_a` through `var_e`. For each (*input, parameter*) pair, I have to write those values via the external interface, then read the response. Thus, I'm limited to collecting data one point at a time in a loop.

I want to return a pandas DataFrame for **each** data variable over the **n** x **m** input space. Any non-valid data should be stored as 'nan'.

My skeleton code looks as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def run_test(inputs, parameters):
    
    """
    TODO#1: Initialise data structures.
    """

    for n in inputs:
            set_input(n)  # Write value to external interface.

            """
            TODO#2: Clear previous data (important as default should be nan).
            """

            for m in parameters:
                set_parameter(m) # Write value to external interface.
                
                # Read data (from external interface).
                var_a, var_b, var_c = read_var_abc() 
                var_d, var_e = read_var_de()

                # Store values.
               """
               TODO#3: Store current values of each var for this parameter value.
               """
            
            # Save recorded data.
            """
            TODO#4: Store a column of data for each var to its dataframe.
            """

    return dataframes
```

What I'm looking for is the 'nicest' or most Pythonic way to set up and iterate over the data structures. Ideally I want to generalise this (potentially add more variables) and avoid 5 lines repeating `var_x_array[i] = var_x`. I've presented some options I've explored below.

## Attempt 1: Keep a list of references to current data arrays.

First I tried making a `np.array` for each variable, and keeping a list 'variables' which stored a reference to each array. I kept a parallel list containing the DataFrame for each variable, and populated it column-by-column in the loop.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def run_test(inputs, parameters)
    """
    TODO#1: Initialise data structures.
    """
    var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d, var_e = (np.empty(len(parameters)) for _ in range(5))
    variables = [var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d, var_e]  # List of references to mutable arrays.
    dataframes = [pd.DataFrame(index=parameters, columns=inputs) for _ in variables]

    for n in inputs:
            set_input(n) # Write value to external interface.

            """
            TODO#2: Clear previous data (important as default should be nan).
            """
            for i,v in enumerate(variables):
                variables[i].fill(np.nan)


            for i,m in enumerate(parameters):
                set_parameter(m) # Write value to external interface.
                
                # Read data (from external interface) AND store values.
                """
                TODO#3: Store current values of each var for this parameter value.
                """
                var_a[i], var_b[i], var_c[i] = read_var_abc() 
                var_d[i], var_e[i] = read_var_de()
            
            # Save recorded data.
            """
            TODO#4: Store a column of data for each var to its dataframe.
            """
            for i,v in enumerate(variables):
                dataframes[i][n] = v  # Fill column for input 'n' in the 'i'-th DataFrame

    return dataframes # List of DataFrames.
```

**Pros**:

- Can easily clear and store data with iteration over 'variables'.

**Cons**:

- Could be awkward to extend with more variables.
- DataFrames are arbitratily ordered (they aren't sequential a,b,c,d,e in reality!). A caller has to assume/know what data is stored in each DataFrame.

## Attempt 2: Dictionaries of current data arrays and DataFrames.

Next, I considered storing all data arrays and DataFrames in dictionaries, to make explicit what data belongs to each array by a named key (not just by assumed position in list).

```py
def run_test(inputs, parameters):
    """
    TODO#1: Initialise data structures.
    """
    var_names = ["var_a", "var_b", "var_c", "var_d", "var_e"]  
    dataframes = {v: pd.DataFrame(index=parameters, columns=inputs) for v in var_names}
    data = {v: np.empty(len(parameters)) for v in var_names}

    for n in inputs:
            set_input(n) # Write value to external interface.

            """
            TODO#2: Clear previous data (important as default should be nan).
            """
            for array in data.values():
                array.fill(np.nan)

            for i, m in enumerate(parameters):
                set_parameter(m) # Write value to external interface.
                
                # Read data (from external interface).
                """
                TODO#3: Store current values of each var for this parameter value.
                """
                data['var_a'][i], data['var_b'][i], data['var_c'][i] = read_var_abc()
                data['var_d'][i], data['var_e'][i] = read_var_de()
            
            # Save recorded data.
            """
            TODO#4: Store a column of data for each var to its dataframe.
            """
            for v in var_names:
                dataframes[v][n] = data[v]


    return dataframes # Dict of str:DataFrame pairs.
```

**Pros**:

- Output dict clearly and obviously shows what variable each DataFrame holds by the name in the key.

**Cons**:

- Have to manually manage variable names as strings, especially when getting data (TODO#3).
- Just overkill in general maybe?

Think my biggest gut feeling against is just how gross it is around TODO#3. The only other way I thought of was making a local variable for each of `var_a` to `var_e`, then filling the dictionary. However, I couldn't think of any way to do that iteratively without using `locals()` which feels gross.

Any ideas? What approaches are 'best' here?

Comment: why don't you just create all the Dataframes you need at the start, and then directly fill them with your method calls? having `var_a` to `var_e` used everywhere also is kind of a code smell... why do you need these temporary variable names? could you not use a list with these 5 values?

Comment: @JeanotZubler

`var_a` through `var_e` are just generic placeholder names - these are actually independent measurements (`voltage`, `current`, etc.). I can't split up my method calls, as they are from two independent sensors that dump a collection of readings at once.

For each (input, parameter) pair, I have to write these values via the external interface. Thus, I'm limited to collecting data one point at a time in a loop. 
(Have edited post to clarify this)

Could you please provide some sample code demonstrating how you would implement your suggestion? Cheers :)

Comment: Some general suggestions: use one dataframe with multilevel index. use input and parameter as index, and the different variables as columns. if you **really** need seperate DFs, you can do something like `df["var_a"].unstack(level=1)`. I also don't see the point in using arrays. you could extract your TODO3 into its own method, that returns a single dictionary. You can then append this dictionary to your DF.

Comment: While I generally dislike the term "pythonic", talk of `arrays` and "one element at at time", is clearly a mismatch.  Arrays are the wrong structure if you need to work element by element - they are intended for whole-array operations.